# ServiceConfigurationError - Keycloak config does not found the SPI User Storage Provider

Tags: java, spring, ejb, wildfly, keycloak

I have configured a Spring Boot project with connection to Keycloak, and also I want to install a Custom SPI User Provider external to Keycloak.

I did all the steps to do the Provider and ProviderFactory, and also the file in META-INF/services, and now Wildfly fails with,

```
14:20:43,656 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server@9.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.8.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1737)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.8.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1699)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.8.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1557)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory not found
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1211)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.DefaultProviderLoader.load(DefaultProviderLoader.java:60)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.ProviderManager.load(ProviderManager.java:92)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.loadFactories(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:214)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.deploy(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:115)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.ProviderManagerRegistry.deploy(ProviderManagerRegistry.java:42)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-server-subsystem@7.0.0//org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor.deploy(KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server@9.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more

14:20:43,657 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory not found"}}
14:20:43,658 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"focusoc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\"
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider gcs.fds.focusoc.keycloak.spi.LoginStorageProviderFactory not found"}}
```

Anyone knows what it is happening?

**Edit:**

After differents modifications (adding the persistence.xml, jboss-deployment-structure.xml, ...) now I still have the next error:

```
12:25:47,301 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."login-provider-focusoc.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."login-provider-focusoc.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "login-provider-focusoc.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server@9.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.8.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1737)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.8.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1699)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.8.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1557)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link gcs/fds/focusoc/keycloak/spi/LoginStorageProvider (Module "deployment.login-provider-focusoc.jar" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/storage/UserStorageProvider
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:238)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.server@9.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more

12:25:47,302 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"login-provider-focusoc.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"login-provider-focusoc.jar\"
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link gcs/fds/focusoc/keycloak/spi/LoginStorageProvider (Module \"deployment.login-provider-focusoc.jar\" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/storage/UserStorageProvider"}}
```

Anyone knows what it is happeing? Or it's happenned to anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it doing the manual installation with the command explained in the documentation and adding the provider in the standalone.